# Styles getting lost with Webpack media-query-plugin

Tags: webpack, sass

I'm trying to split CSS output into a number of files based on media-queries. I'm using Webpack 4 as a dev/build tool to generate the static assets used by another system.
The issue is when adding the MediaQueryPlugin to the webpack.config.js (see below) the dist.css ends up just containing the print media query and nothing else. I have a dist-print.css and a main-print.css (both remain empty), there are no errors in the console.
I must be missing something very simple! (note the scss file is main.scss)
Any ideas?

```
...
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const MediaQueryPlugin = require('media-query-plugin');
...

module.exports = (env, options) => ({
...
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: [
        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        'css-loader',
        MediaQueryPlugin.loader,
        'postcss-loader',
        'sass-loader'
      ]
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
    }],
    plugins: [
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: `css/dist.css`
      }),
      new MediaQueryPlugin({
        include: [
          'main'
        ],
        queries: {
          print: 'print',
        }
      }),
      new CleanWebpackPlugin(['assets'], {
        root: `${__dirname}/${pkg.build.dest_folder}`
      }),
    ],
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple thing I missed was the critical variable in the filename. Works as expected after this change

```
  new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: `css/[name].css`
  }),
```